# How to export message to output window like Application output from Qtcreator self-made plugin

Tags: plugins, qt-creator

All,

I am developing a Qtcreator plugin by myself, basically is to add a menu item to invoke an external python script, the problem I met is how to export message to output window, I tried qDebug, cout, which can only print the message to the Parent Qtcreator(the one I developing plugin), what I need is to export the message to output window of Qtcreator I built, does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks,
Le

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to is call [`Core::MessageManager::write`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtcreator-extending/core-messagemanager.html) which prints the output to the "General" output pane.

To show output in a tab in the application output pane, you need to implement a [`ProjectExplorer::RunControl`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtcreator-extending/projectexplorer-runcontrol.html) and start that through [`ProjectExplorer::ProjectExplorerPlugin::startRunControl`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtcreator-extending/projectexplorer-projectexplorerplugin.html#startRunControl).